# Error in Theano loop: Outputs_info dim and fn output dim mismatch in scan

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

I am a beginner with Theano, and I am working from an example of another's code that, presumably, worked at some point (however, I have modified it...but I'm pretty sure my modifications have nothing to do with what is going wrong at the moment).

Anyhow, I am trying to debug a Theano Scan...and I think what I am observing is a fundamental error in the scan function.

```
U, V, W = self.U, self.V, self.W
x = T.ivector('x')
y = T.ivector('y')
def forward_prop_step(x_t, s_t_prev, U, V, W):
    s_t = T.tanh(U.dot(x_t) + V.dot(s_t_prev))
    o_t = T.tanh(W.dot(s_t))
    return [o_t,s_t]
[o,s], updates = theano.scan(
        forward_prop_step,
        sequences=x,
        outputs_info=[None, dict(initial=T.zeros(self.hidden_dim))],
        non_sequences=[U, V, W],
        truncate_gradient=self.bptt_truncate,
        strict=True)
```

`U` is an `m x n` matrix, `V` is an `n x n` matrix, and `W` is an `n x o` matrix...and `self.bptt_truncate` is a scalar (4).   but I don't think the internals of my function are what are failing at the moment.

The error I get is:

> ValueError: When compiling the inner function of scan the following error has been encountered: The initial state (`outputs_info` in scan nomenclature) of variable IncSubtensor{Set;:int64:}.0 (argument number 1) has 2 dimension(s), while the result of the inner function (`fn`) has 2 dimension(s) (should be one less than the initial state).

I have tried altering the dimensions of outputs_info, and the return dimensions of `forward_prop_step`, but nothing seems to work so far.

I am currently looking into the documentation...but, from the documentation, it seems like what I am doing is correct (below is the example from the documentation):

```
def oneStep(u_tm4, u_t, x_tm3, x_tm1, y_tm1, W, W_in_1, W_in_2,  W_feedback, W_out):

    x_t = T.tanh(theano.dot(x_tm1, W) + \
                 theano.dot(u_t,   W_in_1) + \
                 theano.dot(u_tm4, W_in_2) + \
                 theano.dot(y_tm1, W_feedback))
    y_t = theano.dot(x_tm3, W_out)

    return [x_t, y_t]
```

And here is the documentation scan:

```
W = T.matrix()
W_in_1 = T.matrix()
W_in_2 = T.matrix()
W_feedback = T.matrix()
W_out = T.matrix()

u = T.matrix() # it is a sequence of vectors
x0 = T.matrix() # initial state of x has to be a matrix, since
                # it has to cover x[-3]
y0 = T.vector() # y0 is just a vector since scan has only to provide
                # y[-1]


([x_vals, y_vals], updates) = theano.scan(fn=oneStep,
                                          sequences=dict(input=u, taps=[-4,-0]),
                                          outputs_info=[dict(initial=x0, taps=[-3,-1]), y0],
                                          non_sequences=[W, W_in_1, W_in_2, W_feedback, W_out],
                                          strict=True)
     # for second input y, scan adds -1 in output_taps by default
```

The return of the function is: '[x_t,y_t]' and the `outputs_info` is `[dict(initial=x0, taps=[-3,-1]), y0]`...

While in my implementation, the return of the function is: `[o_t,s_t]` and the `outputs_info` is `[None, dict(initial=T.zeros(self.hidden_dim))]`...which makes sense, since I have no reason to pass my output into the function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem when applying RNN for NLP task. This error occurs because of the type of `x_t` argument of `forward_prop_step` function, which is **scalar** because of iterating through the ivector `x`.

Solution here is to use a **vector**. Here, for example, `x_tv` is a vector which have all zeros and 1 at `x_t` index.

```
def forward_prop_step(x_t, s_t_prev, U, V, W):
    x_tv = T.eye(1, m=input_size, k=x_t)[0]
    s_t = T.tanh(U.dot(x_tv) + V.dot(s_t_prev))
    o_t = T.tanh(W.dot(s_t))
    return [o_t, s_t]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following? Note the difference with `(self.hidden_dim, )` and `(self.hidden_dim)`

```
outputs_info=[None, dict(initial=T.zeros((self.hidden_dim, )))],
```